# Why are these images not taking up the entire space in the line but instead shifting down?

Tags: html, css, image

Screenshot showing 2 img in a line when it should have been 3
[image]

i've tried everything but the problem doesn't seem to go away.
i believe my maths is correct.

It works as expected in my friends computer though.

Honestly there is not much code but three img tags for 3 images and in css i did,

```css
img {
           width: 30%;
           margin: 1.666%;  /*or :calc(10%/6); */
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <img src="picture/1.jpg">
    <img src="picture/2.jpg">
    <img src="picture/3.jpg">
</body>
```

Now if my maths is correct which i think it is all 3 images should appear in a single line but they dont.

Comment: A good resource to help you is [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linebreaks in the code create spaces between the images which are "added" between the margins (like between words – images are inline elements). If you write all three images into one line in the HTML code (without any spaces between them), it works as desired:

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1.666%;
  /*or :calc(10%/6); */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="picture/1.jpg"><img src="picture/2.jpg"><img src="picture/3.jpg">
</body>
```